# Is it possible to create many brokers on Spring Websocket configuration?

Tags: java, stomp, spring-websocket

I have an application that require receive different types of messages from the server. I have created an approach that allows many simple brokers, but I can't find information if it is a good or correct way to use:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
   config.enableSimpleBroker("/stats", "/queue", /event");
   config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/service");
}
```

It works fine. I'd like to now if this is correct. If so, how many brokers can we configure? Are there problems with this approach? Is /queue and /topic needed for the broker?

Thanks a lot!